# Why won't my sine method work

Tags: java

I'm a beginner programmer and new to stackoverflow.

So i have been making a Math Formula Solver and I have 4 formulas up and functioning. I am working on my Sine formula solver and it won't work. I use a scanner and switch to select the formula and input the variables. Here is what i have.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter '0' for list of formula call numbers");
    System.out.print("Enter the formula request number: " );
    int mFormula = input.nextInt();
    switch(mFormula)
{
    case 5 :
            System.out.println("Sine Problem Solver, please enter your variables below: ");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Value for known side: ");
            int x = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Value for degrees: ");
            int x3 = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println();
            double Sine = (x * Math.sin(x3));
            System.out.print("The side length is: " + Sine);break;
}
```

im just really confused on why it isn't working.

Comment: Please add more details, `it doesn't work` is not very clear for us that try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your main problem is that `Math.sin` doesn't take degrees but radians. Try

```
Math.sin(Math.toRadians(x3))
```

Comment: You are the man. i tried so many different things to change it to degrees and i kept getting wonky answers. thank you so much.